# Why doesn't limestone thermally decompose instead of turning to marble?

Tags: physical-chemistry, geochemistry

When limestone is buried and put under intense heat and pressure, why does it turn to marble instead of thermally decomposing into calcium oxide and carbon dioxide?

Comment: [This table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate#Calcination_equilibrium) relating the vapour pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ above a sample of limestone is important. In air, $\ce{CaCO3}$ beings decomposing slowly at about 600°C via the reaction $\ce{CaCO3\ _{(s)} -> CaO\ _{(s)} + CO2\ _{(g)}}$, but under pressure *the equilibrium is shifted to the left* and higher temperatures are in turn needed to decompose the limestone.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer:**

It's not hot enough, and the pressure is too high.

**Long answer:**

You say:

> intense heat and pressure

The key word is pressure rather than heat. Let's look at the phase diagram of the CaO and CO<sub>2</sub> compositional system:

[image: Calcium oxide and carbon dioxide phase diagram]
<sup>(Calculated and plotted using [Perple_X](http://www.perplex.ethz.ch/))</sup>

Pure limestone and marble are composed of calcium carbonate: CaCO<sub>3</sub>. In air, the temperature required for calcium carbonate decomposition is 898 °C (considering simple equilibrium and ignoring any [vapour pressure effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate#Calcination_equilibrium)). As pressure increases, the temperature requirement for this equilibrium decomposition increases very rapidly. It increases so fast that in fact, at above 80 bar, the calcium carbonate will melt into a liquid (call it calcium carbonate magma or lava) instead of decomposing to lime and carbon dioxide.

While 80 bar may seem a lot for us humans (it is higher than the [pressure exerted by a 45 kg woman wearing stiletto heels](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=80%20bar)), it is nothing compared to the pressure below us, deep in the Earth. Marble forms at a wide pressure range, but for this discussion let's say that it's somewhere between 2 and 10 kbar. That's 2000 to 10000 bar! Way off the scale of the phase diagram. Also, marble forms in the temperature range of 300 to 800 °C. Again, it's not even enough to melt the calcium carbonate, let alone decompose it to gas.